# I want to know is it possible and will it be implemented to record calls on Android 7?

Tags: android, phone-call, mediarecorder, android-7.0-nougat, audio-source

I have tried AudioSource VOICE_CALL,DEFAULT,VOICE_COMMUNICATION,MIC
I am not able to get the other side voice only on Nougat devices, rest of working fine.
I dont know where I am facing problem in Nougat.
My Code is below

```
           recorder = new MediaRecorder();
             if (audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn()) {
                recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
             } else if (!audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn()) {
                recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
             }
             recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
             recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

I want to know is it possible and will it be implemented to record calls on Android 7?

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT permission.

From 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html

> Capturing from VOICE_CALL source requires the CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT permission.

Comment: I added to request the CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT permission. but  Same problem reaming.

Comment: He can use root to elevate privileges